# Limit available fonts

Tags: 2010

I am looking for a way to limit the available fonts in SharePoint 2010 to only Arial.

I want to do this with the least amount of effort, and I do not want to use a Custom style for the RichHtmlField because it means I would have to edit all the page layouts and upload them to all the site collections.

I am already using a custom masterpage and custom css, so a way to edit it in one of those two would be the perfect solution.

So once again I am looking for a way in which I do not have to edit the page layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Those styles are coming from htmleditorstyles.css file under Style Library/en-us/Themable/Core Styles

```
.ms-rteFontFace-1
{
  -ms-name:"Tahoma";
  font-family: tahoma;
}
.ms-rteFontFace-2
{
  -ms-name:"Courier";
  font-family: courier, monospace;
}
.ms-rteFontFace-3
{
  -ms-name:"Times New Roman";
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
.ms-rteFontFace-4
{
  -ms-name:"Comic Sans";
  font-family: "Comic Sans", "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
```

The only way I can think of achieving it is to remove those unwanted .ms-rteFontFace styles and keep whatever you want.